# (C#) Unable to get the lowest value from an array containing doubles

Tags: c#, arrays, min

I am still pretty new to C#, this is my second day coding.
I am unable to get the lowest Value from an array containing doubles.

for example:

```
double [] arr = { 5.5 , 6.5 , 8.19 };
double max = (arr.Min);
```

This Code doesn't seem to work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `double max = arr.Min();` although I'm not sure why you'd call the variable `max` if it actually contains the minimum value.

Comment: You need to **call** the method.. `arr.Min` is a delegate, `arr.Min()` is the result of calling that method.

Comment: using Linq extensions you can call `Min()` on the arr viariable to get the min value from the collection.

Comment: Oh, so I made a mistake in my syntax I guess.. I feel pretty dumb right now.

Comment: Anyways, thanks a lot for the help, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @KingsChannel Don't feel bad if it's your second day. Everybody has to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

```
double [] arr = { 5.5 , 6.5 , 8.19 };
double minimum = arr.Min();
```

Note that this will give you an error if the array is empty. You can check first and then decide what to do if the array is empty:

```
double [] arr = { 5.5 , 6.5 , 8.19 };
double minimum = 0;

if (arr.Length > 0)
{
    minimum = arr.Min();
}
else
{
    // Add code to do something if the array is empty
}
```

Comment: I think if(arr.Any()) is clearer (but that requires using System.Linq).

Comment: Or simple use a nullable type `double?`

Comment: @Neil `Min` requires System.Linq.

Comment: @Neil Calling .Any() does add the overhead of creating an enumerator and iterating to the first result. I know in most cases that's probably fine (and I use it all the time in production code), but in a simple example I thought it best to use .Length.

Comment: I think it depends on the implementation of the collection.  In this case, Array.Any() probably just does { return this.Length!=0;}.  The difference is showing the intention of the developer to the next person looking at the code.

Comment: @Neil It doesn't. .Any() is a Linq method and the linq method uses an enumerator (check with something like DotPeek, if needs be). Feel free to split hairs if needs be. Everyone I've worked with would have the sense to understand this. YMMV.